# Updating the "existing literary works" close reason to point to Literature SE?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

One of the current custom close reasons of Writing SE is:

> The community has decided that questions about existing literary works, except in a writing-specific context, are off-topic. For more information, see [this meta answer](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/764/26).

Asking about existing literary works is off-topic on a site about Writing; that makes sense. But there are other SE sites which are specifically devoted to questions about existing literary works; wouldn't it be nice to mention them in the close reason too, give a pointer to an OP who might have asked a good question but on the wrong site?

I'm thinking primarily of [Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/), which accepts all sorts of questions about existing literary works (note: not recommendation or open-ended list questions!) There's also [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) and [Anime and Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/), but as those cater only to specific subsets of "literary works" (plus other stuff as well), I wouldn't suggest mentioning those in the close reason, in case an OP of a non-sci-fi/fantasy non-manga question gets confused by being pointed there.

**Can we update the close reason text to link to Literature SE as a potential alternative venue for such questions?**

Comment: Updating the community-specific close reasons is something the mods can do, and something I'm definitely willing to do. Though perhaps a more complete overhaul of all the close reasons is in order. In which case waiting until after the election is complete may be a good idea.

Comment: @linksassin Yeah, I realised after composing this meta that Writing hasn't yet updated its close reasons to take advantage of the new(ish) audience-specific close reason texts. I'll be happy to help with that drafting process, or you can use as templates my meta posts from my mod sites ([Literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1549/17), [SFF 1](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13275/31394), [SFF 2](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13305/31394)). Or did you mean overhauling in the sense of actually changing what gets closed as off-topic here?

Comment: Both, the community has changed a lot since our on-topic definition was created and I think it might be time to revisit both what the reasons are and how they are presented.